# NSException When repeating NSTask

Tags: objective-c

I have this code that is suppose to check certain settings and log the results. The first setting check works correctly but the next one fails. Here is the code block:

```
//init classes
    CocoaLogging *logFile = [[CocoaLogging alloc]init];

    NSString * result;
    NSInteger * state;
    NSPipe *pipe=[[NSPipe alloc] init];
    NSFileHandle *handle;
    NSString * cmd = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @"/usr/bin/defaults"];

    //Start logging
    NSString *logText;
    NSString *logPath;
    BOOL logSuccess;

    NSLog(@"Start Settings Enforcer");

    logPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", NSHomeDirectory(), LOGFILE_PATH];
    if (! [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:logPath isDirectory:NO])
    {
        logSuccess = [logFile createLogFile:logPath];
        if (logSuccess)
        {
            logText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @"Start Settings Enforcer"];
            [logFile makeLogEntry:logText to:logPath];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        logPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", NSHomeDirectory(), LOGFILE_PATH];

        logText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @"Start Settings Enforcer"];
        logSuccess = [logFile makeLogEntry:logText to:logPath];
    }


    //check status of firewall
    //defaults read "/Library/Preferences/com.apple.alf" globalstate
    //array of commandline args
    NSMutableArray *firewallArgs = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"-currentHost", @"read", @"/Library/Preferences/com.apple.alf", @"globalstate", nil];

    //init the task
    NSTask *firewall=[[NSTask alloc] init];

    //define the command to run
    [firewall setLaunchPath:cmd];
    [firewall setArguments:firewallArgs];
    [firewall setStandardOutput:pipe];
    handle=[pipe fileHandleForReading];

    //run the command
    [firewall launch];



    // convert NSData -> NSString
    result = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:[handle readDataToEndOfFile]encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    state = [result intValue];

    NSLog(@"%@", result);
    if (state == 1)
    {
        NSLog(@"firewall is on");
        logText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @"firewall is on"];
        logSuccess = [logFile makeLogEntry:logText to:logPath];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"firewall is off");
        logText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @"firewall is off"];
        logSuccess = [logFile makeLogEntry:logText to:logPath];
    }


    [firewallArgs removeAllObjects];
    [handle closeFile];
    [firewall terminate];

    //check screensaver on
    //defaults read ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.screensaver askForPassword

    NSString * plistPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @"~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.screensaver"];
    plistPath = [plistPath stringByExpandingTildeInPath];

    //array of commandline args
    NSMutableArray *ssOnArgs = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"read", plistPath, @"askForPassword", nil];


    //init the task
    NSTask *ssOn=[[NSTask alloc] init];

    //define the command to run
    [ssOn setLaunchPath:cmd];
    [ssOn setArguments:ssOnArgs];
    [ssOn setStandardOutput:pipe];
    handle=[pipe fileHandleForReading];

    //run the command
    [ssOn launch];

    // convert NSData -> NSString
    result = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:[handle readDataToEndOfFile]encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    state = [result intValue];

    if (state == 1)
    {
        NSLog(@"screensaver is on");
        logText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @"screensaver is on"];
        logSuccess = [logFile makeLogEntry:logText to:logPath];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"screensaver is off");
        logText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @"screensaver is off"];
        logSuccess = [logFile makeLogEntry:logText to:logPath];
    }


    NSLog(@"Check-in complete");
    logText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @"Check-in complete."];
    logSuccess = [logFile makeLogEntry:logText to:logPath];
}
return 0;
```

}

Here is the error:

> 2014-03-31 12:58:11.630 SettingsEnforcer[5379:303] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSFileHandleOperationException', reason: '** -[NSConcreteFileHandle fileDescriptor]: No such process'
>   ** First throw call stack:
>   (
>       0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8ce4825c __exceptionPreprocess + 172
>       1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff8b075e75 objc_exception_throw + 43
>       2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8ce4810c +[NSException raise:format:] + 204
>       3   Foundation                          0x00007fff8ba9a29d -[NSConcreteFileHandle fileDescriptor] + 30
>       4   Foundation                          0x00007fff8bb2fb97 -[NSConcreteTask launchWithDictionary:] + 2114
>       5   SettingsEnforcer                    0x0000000100001e1e main + 2126
>       6   libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff91e555fd start + 1
>   )
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

I hope someone smarter than I can spot the error.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are recycling the `NSPipe` instance.   Create a new pipe for the second task.

Comment: this helped me ( 06-july-2015 )